# Green function derived from the idea of position representation in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions

I am trying to study green's function by using a lecture by NPTEL its link is
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZJ7v6VZQ32k&t=439s
 I don't get  this step by him at the minute of ten.

$$D_x G(x,x^{'}) =\langle x|x'\rangle =\delta (x-x').$$

Please  give your precious little time to help me

Comment: Are you asking about the first or second equality?

Comment: first equality,

Comment: What do you think is missing in Prof. Balakrishnan's argument?

Comment: I don't get how position representation of some operator operates on position representation of inverse of that operator gives inner product of x with x'

Comment: An operator times its inverse yields the identity, which, in the position representation, is visibly the position delta function, no?

Comment: how dirac delta function is the position  representation of identity operator, can you clarify it please @Cosmas Zachos